# Aptana studio 3 snippets

Tags: aptana, code-snippets, aptana3

where to edit snippets in aptana studio 3

im used to gedit snippets plugin

when i go to command menu < html < conditional command < ie conditonal command
it says not defined

is there a way we can add our own snippets and how to trigger them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. There is a document here on how to create your own snippets:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+snippet