# Escape slashes on Aptana Ruby Snippet

Tags: ruby, aptana, code-snippets

I'm trying to create a new snippet on Aptana like this:

```
snippet "dump em arquivo" do |s|
  s.trigger = "debug"
  s.scope = 'source.php'
  s.expansion = "//debug
file_put_contents('${2:/var/d_tmp/debug.log}', print_r(${1}, true) . \"\\n\", ${3:LOCK_EX});"
end
```

...But on the variable `${2:/var/d_tmp/debug.log}` the `/ (slash)` works as an option list and backslashing it doen't work either (`${2:\/var\/d_tmp\/debug.log}`).

So, how can I escape the slashes to make the snippet actually works, outputing the entire string.
The desired output should be like this:

```
//debug
file_put_contents('/var/d_tmp/debug.log', print_r(, true) . "\n", LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer through [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470757/aptana-studio-3-snippets).

As example in [app accelerator wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+snippet#CreatingaNewSnippet-SpecialCharacters) escaping is done with `two backslashes`.

```
snippet "dump em arquivo" do |s|
  s.trigger = "debug"
  s.scope = 'source.php'
  s.expansion = "//debug
file_put_contents('${2:\\/var\\/d_tmp\\/debug.log}', print_r(${1}, true) . \"\\n\", ${3:LOCK_EX});"
end
```